# Why can't I select a column from a subquery in teredata?

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata

I know this has been asked but I don't have access to JOIN or pretty much anything with the Teredata SQL assistant and I want to know why this doesn't work. I have a subquery that displays the name of an agent and counts their transactions for destinations to France. If they have over 10 transactions to France the number of transactions and names are displayed.

I want to take this working SELECT statement and put it as a sub query. Then I want to only take the agent_name from this sub query.

Why won't it let me do this?

I tried:

```
   DATABASE database;
   SELECT agent_name FROM
   (SELECT COUNT (*) number, agent_name 
   FROM TRANSAC
   WHERE TRANSAC.cust_name = CUSTOMER.cname 
   AND CUSTOMER.destination = 'France'
   GROUP BY agent_name
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 9;)
```

and I tried

```
 DATABASE database;
 SELECT agent_name FROM TRANSAC WHERE agent_name IN
 (SELECT COUNT (*) number, agent_name 
 FROM TRANSAC
 WHERE TRANSAC.cust_name = CUSTOMER.cname 
 AND CUSTOMER.destination = 'France'
 GROUP BY agent_name
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 9;)
```

**Update** you can select from a subquery by using an alias

```
 DATABASE redeclectus;
 SELECT t.agent_name 
 FROM
 (SELECT COUNT (*) number, agent_name FROM TRANSAC
 WHERE TRANSAC.cust_name = CUSTOMER.cname AND
 CUSTOMER.destination = 'Ottawa'
 GROUP BY agent_name
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 9) t;
```

Comment: no - do I have to make it a view?

Comment: Sure you could do that.

Comment: Please tag question with *teradata* and check again as [joins](http://www.teradatawiki.net/2013/09/Teradata-Joins.html) are fundamental in SQL and most RDMS support it.

Comment: What happens when you actually use correct join syntax?  What error do you receive?  As long as you have SELECT permission on the tables you should be able to join.  If you don't have select permission then nothing you do will work.  If you use correct join syntax and get an error saying that the table does not exist or you do not have permissions, then you need SELECT permission.  If you get some error about running out of spool then you need to talk to a DBA about the amount of spool space allowed for your user account.  if you get some other error then you probably have bad syntax.